# pre-selecting two dropdowns with ng-selected in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have two `select` dropdowns with the first one populating the second one. I have the first one pre-selected using `ng-selected` however I cannot work out how to have the second dropdown selected. I have tried using `$scope.Colours.options` but get error: `Cannot read property 'options' of undefined error in console log.`

```
    <label for="ColourGroup">Colour Group</label>
    <select id="ColourGroup" class="form-control" ng-model="ColourGroup" ng-options="cgroup as cgroup.a for cgroup in cgroups track by cgroup.v" ng-selected="{{selected.v == cgroup.v}}"></select>


    <label for="Colours">Colour/Woodgrain</label>
    <select id="Colours" class="form-control" ng-model="Colours.options" ng-options="option as option.name for option in ColourGroup.options track by option.id"><option value="">Choose Colour / Woodgrain</option></select>
```

I have a plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/mFdRlX2CjZnsm8EFZMiZ?p=preview

If someone can point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? The plunker seems to be working? I might be misunderstanding though.

Comment: I'm trying to use ng-selected on the second dropdown, e.g: Colour Group: 'Plain' and Colour/Woodgrain: 'Bright White Thickness 18mm' are both selected.

Answer (score 0):

Directives ng-init and ng-change can handle it. Just replace form tag with this one. Also you can remove select init at your controller.

```
<form class="form form-inline" ng-controller="Ctrl">

    <label for="ColourGroup">Colour Group</label>
    <select id="ColourGroup" class="form-control" ng-model="ColourGroup" ng-options="cgroup as cgroup.a for cgroup in cgroups track by cgroup.v" ng-init="ColourGroup=cgroups[0]" ng-change="Colours=ColourGroup.options[0]"></select>


    <label for="Colours">Colour/Woodgrain</label>
    <select id="Colours" class="form-control" ng-model="Colours" ng-options="option as option.name for option in ColourGroup.options track by option.id" ng-init="Colours=ColourGroup.options[0]"></select>

</form>
```